# Android Thumbnail storage and deletion

Tags: android

In my application, I display thumbnail image as well as the corresponding full size image.The user can delete the image. 
Does android delete the thumbnail image automatically when the full size image is deleted? Or do we need to delete the thumbnail image when the full size image is deleted? If so please let me know how to delete the thumbnail.
Thanks

Comment: You haven't given enough detail to know the answer. If you're managing the thumbnail images, do you write them to files or just ask Android to get you a thumbnail bitmap from a file? If you just ask for a thumbnail image from a file, it only exists as a bitmap in memory and does not create a new file. The Gallery app creates thumbnail files so that it can display them more quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the information.I'm using the built in camera app and I'm not managing the thumbnail images. I'm using the following method to retrieve the thumbnail image which of course returns the bitmap. MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),imageId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null));  But even after    the full image has been deleted,the thumbnail image still exists. As you mentioned,it seems the Gallery app creates the thumbnail file. So if I delete the full image,is there any way to delete the thumbnail image created by the Gallery app programmatically?